# Unable to remotly connect to SSL enabled application from Hawtio

Tags: ssl, apache-camel, hawtio, jolokia

I am not able to remotly connect to my springboot microservice from hawtio.
If i am disabling ssl then i am able to see camel routes in hawtio console.

[hawtio console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MvsT.jpg)

Error in response:
Request URL: http://localhost:8090/hawtio/proxy/https/lxapptaldev003/4150/jolokia/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

Add this JVM parameter:

```
-Dhawtio.proxyDisableCertificateValidation=true
```

Credit:
  [Google-Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hawtio/WtAJvOSo1BY)